# String input in a function within a switch-case statement results in infinite loop and bypassing of input?

Tags: c++

Novice trying to self teach himself C++ here.

Here is the code for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
void function1(int);
void function2(int);
void function3(int);

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int input = 0;
    while (input != 4){
      cout << "Prompt" << endl;
      cin >> input;
      switch(input) {
           case 1:
              function1(input);
              break;
           case 2:
              function2(input);
              break;
           case 3:
              function3(input);
              break;
           case 4:
              cout << "Program terminated." << endl;
              return 0;
              break;
           default:
              cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
              input = 4; // Exits the while-loop.
              break;

       }
   }
}

void function1(int a) {
    int prompt;
    cout << "Prompt again" << endl;
    cin >> prompt;
    if (!cin){
        cout << "Input is not a number." << endl;
        return;
    }
}

void function2(int a) {
}

void function3(int a) {
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make a function1 that detects if a specific input was a string or a char instead of an integer, and then say that it is not a number, then go back to the switch case statements. Once it detects this though, the statements in the while loop go on forever and completely bypass the cin prompts! I understand from reading other people's questions that the infinite looping might have something to do with using 'int' in a header and inputting a string when an integral is expected, but I don't understand why the code doesn't stop when the cin is prompted or how to bypass it. Any help?

Comment: The stream enters failed state, and all further operation fail. That's it.

Comment: You need to use `cin.clear()` to clear the error state

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (!cin){
    cout << "Input is not a number." << endl;
    return;
}
```

When `cin<<` reads a bad input, its flags are set to an error state. The error state needs to be cleared by resetting the flags to zero, which is done using `cin.clear()`. Change your if-statement to include the `cin.clear()` statement:

```
if (!cin){
    cout << "Input is not a number." << endl;
    cin.clear(); // <-- Add this line
    return;
}
```

When you enter invalid input for `cin <<`, the error flags of `cin<<` are set to 1 (true). That is why we use `cin.clear()`; so that the error flags are reset  to zero, and `cin<<` can accept new input.

Comment: Could the downvoter of this question provide a reason for the downvote?